# Organizing documents in a big hierarchy

Tags: file-management, path

I'm on a task of organizing documents ( like images, .docs, etc )  of all kinds of knowledge in life in such a way that i can later quickly access each category of knowledge and its documents.

I thought of simply using an hierarchy/tree of folders in Windows 7-64bits.
On the end of each branch of the tree/hierarchy ( that is, on the last folder of each direction ) , i would store the documents.

The problem is that over the tenth-level of folders i'm hitting the MAX_PATH_LENGTH of windows, which means my ability to organize those documents is being limited.

I think there is no way to increase the MAX_PATH_LENGTH, correct ?

So, can you guys suggest any other way to create such a big and easily-navigable hierarchy of documents ?
Someone suggested databases, but i can't see how that could help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: These kinds of applications are often done with mind mapping or wiki software (they let you link to, or embed you documents).  There are no practical limits on hierarchy levels and they add the ability to also relate things between branches or to create associations not limited to a strict tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing your paths with  "\\?\" will let you use 32k long pathnames. See [the Microsoft documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath).

Comment: As you probably have read, this won't solve my problem.That's because what i'm interested in doing is creating an hierarchy with more than 10 level of folders. I'm not interested in manipulating the path of each document. It's just that the MAX_PATH_LENGTH is preventing me from creating an hierarchy of folders with more levels.